# ROS2 demo_nodes_py listener "No executable found"?

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble, anaconda

I have tried to install ROS2 humble in conda using [robostack](https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html) on Linux Mint 21.3. When I do so and activate the conda environment I am able to run cpp nodes but not the python ones. I.e when I try to run the demo

```bash
# In terminal 1
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker

# In terminal 2
ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener
```

The talker works but the listener gives `No executable found`. Does anyone know why this might be?

I know usually you need to source the setup.bash file but I thought since I am using conda it would automatically do this? And if it wasn't then the cpp node would also not work? In any case, I tried manually sourcing from where it was installed at `source ~/miniconda3/pkgs/ros-humble-ros-workspace-1.0.2-py39h63710d1_1/setup.zsh` (since I am using zsh as my shell) and I still got the same error.

Update: Seems to work if I install from apt instead... Is there any way to make it work with conda? It looks like I am having the issue described in [this issue](https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-humble/issues/41)

Comment: It seems like your answer will (hopefully) come in the form of the new Github issue that [you've been asked to raise](https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-humble/issues/41#issuecomment-1961046091).

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-humble/issues/150, packages available as of March 2023 in the `robostack-staging` have renamed does executable, so you can run them with:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_py demo_talker
```

and

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_py demo_listener
```

future packages (once ROS 2 Humble will get a rebuilt on Robostack) will have the names aligned with the apt version